# Deployment Error with Vaadin Maven Plugin: Webpack Process Exited with Non-Zero Exit Code

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am encountering an error while trying to deploy my project using the Vaadin Maven Plugin. The error message states: "Webpack process exited with non-zero exit code." I tried adding
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start" to the package.json file as suggested in a forum post, but I'm unsure if this is the correct solution. Below is the relevant excerpt from my package.json file and the error message I'm encountering:

I'm currently using Java 11 for my project.

```
{
  "name": "no-name",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@polymer/polymer": "3.2.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.10",
    "@vaadin/flow-deps": "./target/frontend",
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.9.0",
    "webpack-babel-multi-target-plugin": "2.3.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "5.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.2",
    "raw-loader": "3.0.0"
  },
  "vaadinAppPackageHash": "a627ec62f3664521d4e8c0d8d32aa8a109ff22198200ab6bb9dbc28be22a3a0b"
}
```

error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:14.1.16:build-frontend (default) on project HKR: Webpack process exited with non-zero exit code.
[ERROR] Stderr: 'node:internal/crypto/hash:68
[ERROR]   this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
[ERROR]                   ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
...
[ERROR] Node.js v20.10.0
```

Comment: Why using such old version of vaadin-maven-plugin ... https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-maven-plugin/versions